# How to get the assembly name from MethodDeclarationSyntax object

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using Roslyn I am getting the public methods like this:

```
  var semanticModel = file.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
  var classParser = new ClassParser(semanticModel);
  var tree = file.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().Result;
  var methodDeclarations = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
                            .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                            .Where(method => method.Modifiers.Any(modifier => modifier.Kind() == SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)).ToList();
```

how is it possible to get the assembly name from the MethodDeclarationSyntax object?

Comment: Just curious but why do you need the assembly this will go in instead of the file name?

Comment: Hi @Jlalonde I only need to store the assembly name and I will not use for anything roslyn specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the semantic model, you can query it for symbols. The symbols have references to the information about the assembly they are contained in:

```
foreach (MethodDeclarationSyntax method in methodDeclarations)
{
    var symbol = semanticModel.GetEnclosingSymbol(method.SpanStart);
    var assembly = symbol.ContainingAssembly;
    var assemblyName = assembly.Identity.Name;
}
```